# multiprocessing.Queue() into dictionary with large input size

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

I have a list called *encrypted_messages* containing 126018 strings. Every string is an encrypted message. I also have a function called *decipher* which, given a string and a key (an integer from 9 to 15, both included), returns the decrypted message. I need to decrypt each message using every single key. Since the *decipher* function is computationally expensive and there are a lot of messages, I have implemented a multiprocessing solution.
I have created a multiprocessing.JoinableQueue() called *messages_queue* containing all the encrypted messages and a multiprocessing.Queue() called *results_queue* to store the results. These queues are shared by all processes. The processes obtain messages from *messages_queue*, apply *decipher* to them with all keys and store the result as a list of 2 elements (the key used to decrypt the message and the decrypted message). It looks like this:

```
[9, message_1], [15, message_2], [14, message_3], ...
```

The *results_queue* has 882126 elements, as expected (note that 126018*7 = 882126), where every element is a list.
I want to obtain a dictionary of length 7 from the *results_queue*, where each key is an integer and every value is a list containing all messages decrypted with that key. It should look like this:

```
{9:[decrypted messages using key 9], 10:[decrypted messages using key 10], ...,
15:[decrypted messages using key 15]}
```

I have tried several ways to do this but I am not able to come up with a solution. I share the code below:

```
final_results = {key:[] for key in range(9, 16)}
while not results_queue.empty():
    message = results_queue.get() # Note that this is a list: [key, message]
    final_results[message[0]].append(message[1])
```

I have also tried to create first a list like this(I can create the dictionary from the list):

```
results = []
results_queue.put('STOP')
while True:
    message = results_queue.get()
    if message == 'STOP':
        break
    results.append(message)
```

I have also tried using an iterator with a sentinel like this:

```
results = []
results_queue.put(None)
for message in iter(results_queue.get, None):
    results.append(message)
```

With all these methods, I lose **a lot** (more than 50%) of the messages. The list should have 882126 lists and every time I run the code it has a different and smaller number. The number looks completely random to me. I do not know how to approach this because the methods above work fine when I use much smaller lists (for example with 100 elements).
Has this issue something to do with the input size? Is my multiprocessing.Queue() too large? I assume this is not a coordination problem between the processes because the Queue() I obtain is what I expect and processes end after that, but maybe I am missing something.

In case it is useful, I am using Python 3.8.5 and Linux Mint 20.2. Any help is welcome since I am a bit stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly there is some issue with process synchronisation. Have you considered appending termination element in process which fills up results_queue? Possibly you put your None/'STOP' when elements are still generated, thus it is not on the end of the queue.

Comment: It could be, but it seems weird because results_queue() is returned by a function. So, only when the function has finished its execution I get the queue. And it has the correct structure because results_queue.qsize() gives me 882126 and when I run results_queue.get() I obtain lists as expected: [9, message_decrypted using key 9], etc. It is after calling the function and when the queue is returned that I put None/'STOP' in it. Anyway, I will try what you suggested once I get home. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code that creates a dictionary that has the for like this

`{key1:[message_1,message_2],key2:[message_3,message_4]}`

message_decoded must be the shape of

`[[key1,message1],[key2,message2]]`

```
dict = {}

messages_decoded = []

for item in messages_decoded:

    if item[0] in dict:
        dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
    else:
        dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]
```

**EDIT**

this codes casts the result queue in to a list.

```
list_messages = [results_queue.get() for _ in range(results_queue.qsize())]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I guess my problem is to obtain the _messages_decoded_ with the shape as you pointed out. What I have is a multiprocessing.Queue(), not a list. I have tried to iterate through it using the results_queue.get() method and append these elements to the list, but a lot of the elements are lost (not appended). As I said, this problem only arises when there are a lot of elements.

Comment: @jakeis I added the conversion of the queue to a list in my code

Comment: It raises an error. type(results_queue) = <class 'multiprocessing.queues.Queue'>. If I try to do list(results_queue) I get the following: TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable

Comment: @jakeis I created a new method that should work :) I tested it with 10**5 Elements and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Indeed, it worked like a charm. That's a clever solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would very much appreciate it if you mark my answer as accepted. Thy in advance